# jQuery validation accept regex

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I'm using jQuery's [Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin to validate a form, which is going well. I know there are [built-in methods](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods) to check for an email address, URL, etc. However, now I want to check for a specific regex (`^[a-zA-Z\ ]+$` in this case, but I'm looking for a general answer).

How can I let the plugin check for a regular expression?

Comment: please try it out and post some code so that we can help you with the particular issue.

Comment: @Ejay try what out? I have no idea what I should do...

Comment: It seems that you want custom validation http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the documentation you've linked to, you'd want to use [`addMethod`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage).

Presumably (I've not used this plugin) with something like:

```
$.validator.addMethod("myMethod", function(text) { 
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\ ]+$/;
    return regex.test(text); 
}, "Custom error message");
```

You could go one step further by making your own regex method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(text, pattern) {
    return pattern.test(text); 
}, "Pattern does not match.");
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! For reference: the documentation says it is _not_ clean to make a general method: "While the temptation is great to add a regex method that checks it's parameter against the value, it is much cleaner to encapsulate those regular expressions inside their own method."

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input."
```

);

now all you need to do to validate against any regex is this:

```
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: "^[a-zA-Z'.\\s]{1,40}$" })
```

I had this sample with me so thought of just pasting it. you are defining a method that checks again your regex pattern and in the below code you apply the rule for particular control(s). change the validation condition and regex pattern with your requirements.